# Facebook SDK for Unity 5.0.2 Beta doesn't work on Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Unity: 4.3.1
Device：Samsung I9300 
Facebook SDK for Unity: 5.0.2 Beta

When I use Facebook SDK for Unity 4.3.6, this works well.

When I use 5.0.2 Beta, it does not work. When I run `FB.Init` on device, it shows

> The Facebook Dll : not Loaded

Facebook settings are the same as in 4.3.6, but I changed the Class Name `com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity` to `com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity` in the facebook.com. But this doesn't  work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 487550674688377" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you also go to "Facebook->Edit Settings" then click "Regenerate Android Manifest"?

There has been some changes to how we handle the SDK for Unity when it exports to Android.  The biggest change is that it'll no longer require `FBUnityPlayerActivity` to be the main class.  It'll require a one time migration to generate the new fields in your `AndroidManifest.xml` which can be accomplished with the regenerate button.

Comment: I know these changes in this new version,I had tried done as your said,but it doesn't work.It can't load the facebook Dll when FB.Init() on the Android device.But it work well in the Unity editor.So I don't know Why.

Comment: Without more details, I'm gonna be shooting in the dark here:
-was the Plugins folder imported with the rest of the package?  You could try first deleting `Plugins/Android/facebook` folder then reimporting.

Could I also see what your `AndroidManifest.xml` currently looks like?

Comment: My AndroidManifest add to my question.I don't change anything,just import facebook sdk to a new project.Facebook settings is ok in the facebook sdk for unity 4.3.6.But fail in 5.0.2 Beta.

Comment: As it turns out, 5.0.2 did not build correctly for Android.  Please download 5.0.3 that we just released: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/

Comment: @BrianJew Since this is an active thread, so I might want to ask a query here. Is it working with the chartboost plugin? If yes, then which activity do we have to enter in the facebook dev dashboard.

Comment: @user1683989, `com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity` should go in the settings in developers.facebook.com.  You can use the chartboost plugin's main activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assets/Plugins/Android/Facebook is missing the bin folder in this release. I don't think there is any Android binary included. Could try building it in Eclipse from the source code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  We fixed this in 5.0.3: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/